# Java loop over half of array

Tags: java, loops, matrix

I would like to loop over half of an array in Java; this is because the matrix will be completely symmetric. If I loop throw i columns and j rows, every time I do an operation of matrix[i][j] I will do the exact same operation to matrix[j][i]. I should be able to save time by not looping over half of the matrix. Any ideas on the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to get a triangle:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
    ..do stuff...
  }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to do stuff just outside the j loop for the main diagonal (matrix[i][i]).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0;i < size; ++i) {
 for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
  result = do_operation(i,j);
  matrix[i][j] = result;
  matrix[j][i] = result ;
 }
}
```

So you invoke the operation method do_operation only once for each pair.

Comment: you had i > size.  Looks like its fixed now.

Comment: that was also obviously a loop that wouldn't work.  I'll be sure to bring my crystal ball with me next time i visit stackoverflow.

Comment: The reason why people answer on SO is not so that the question-poster can cut and paste into their IDE. It is to give an idea as to how to solve the problem. If you were looking for proof-read compilable code, get a babysitter.

Comment: everyone else's code compiles fine.  Is it so hard to stick it in one and test it out?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length - i; j++){
     // operation here
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this the same as Andreas but with a triangle pointing in a different direction?

Comment: Yes basically. I forgot which way the diagonal in a matrix went, so technically this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but let's say you have two arrays representing your rows and columns respectively, and assuming that it's symmetric (as you say):

```
int dimension = rows.Length;
for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++)
{
  int j = (dimension-1) - i; //need dimension-1 to avoid an off-by-one error
  DoSomething(matrix[i][j]);
  DoSomehting(matrix[j][i]);
}
```

This solution has the runtime complexity benefit of only iterating over one loop as opposed to two.

Comment: This code seems to only run DoSomething on every item on the topright-to-bottomleft diagonal...twice. I think the intent was to run DoSomething on every item in the matrix "below" and including that diagonal